# Slack API: Can't send attachments

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to send an attachment using Slack's Python Client but whenever I do I fail. I tried sending it with the Tester too but it still didn't work. Either I get `{"ok": false,"error": "no_text"}` or if I have the text property only the text is going to be sent. This is how I do it. I searched too but didn't found anything.

```
       attachment = json.dumps([{"attachments": [{"fallback": "Reddit Message","color": "#448aff","pretext":"You've got a new Message!","author_name": "Reddit","author_link": "https://reddit.com","author_icon": "imageurl","title": "Reddit Message","title_link": "https://reddit.com/message/inbox","text": "This is what I know about it.","fields": [{"title": "Author:","value": str(item.author),"short": "true"},{"title": "Subject: ","value": str(item.subject),"short": "true"},{"title": "Message:","value": str(item.body),"short": "false"}],"footer": "Reddit API","footer_icon": "anotherimageurl"}]})

sc.api_call("chat.postMessage",channel="U64KWRJAU",attachments=attachment,as_user=True)
```

Help would be appreciated. This should make sense but I don't get it why it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

From your reference, you need to pass attachment as a list. You won't need to have the `attachments` key in a dict containing the list.

```
attachment = json.dumps([
    {
        "fallback": "Reddit Message",
        "color": "#448aff",
        "pretext":"You've got a new Message!",
        "author_name": "Reddit",
        "author_link": "https://reddit.com",
        ....
    }
])

sc.api_call(
    "chat.postMessage", channel="U64KWRJAU",
    attachments=attachment, as_user=True)
```

Comment: But i'm not sending a file. I'm sending a Message Attachment.

Comment: Message Attachment? Do you mean a snippet?

Comment: But then I get: `{u'ok': False, u'error': u'no_text'}`

Comment: You need to provide the `text` property to [chat.PostMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage). Its a mandatory. You can send an empty string though, if you just want the attachment.

Comment: doesn't the documentation say if I have the pretext it wouldn't ask for. Also if I fill out the text field attachment is never sent

Comment: I don't think that's for the attachment text. The docs says text is required for a message unless you're sending only attachments. It seems to be rather inconsistent with the docs that you have to pass an empty text but it is what it is. https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue and found the solution.
The problem is that if only `attachments` field is added into the payload, it will report `no_text` error. But if `text` field is added, slack message will only show the text content.

The solution:
When we want to display `attachments`, we need to add a basic `blocks` field instead of `text` field. Something like

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "bar"
            }
        }
    ],
    "attachments": [
        {
            "color": "#FF0000",
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "section",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "mrkdwn",
                        "text": "foo"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If putting the above payload into the [Slack build kit](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/), it will be a misleading. That's also why I stuck with the issue.

I would recommend to use [chat.postMessage test](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/test) to debug the payload. It will work like a charm.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72036841/3409400