# Unable to post message via the Slack API - getting error 'no_text'

Tags: node.js, slack-api

Why am I getting an error 'no_text' ?

The Json below is valid and is taken from the slack documentation example.

In `bot.postMessage(channel, '', params)` if I populate the second parameter (i.e. replacing ' ' with 'some_text) it prints 'some_text' but without the attachment.

`bot.postMessage(channel, 'some_text', params)` --> works but the attachment doesn't show up.

```
    const element = {
      "text": "Would you like to play a game?",
      "response_type": "in_channel",
      "attachments": [
          {
              "text": "Choose a game to play",
              "fallback": "If you could read this message, you'd be choosing something fun to do right now.",
              "color": "#3AA3E3",
              "attachment_type": "default",
              "callback_id": "game_selection",
              "actions": [
                  {
                      "name": "games_list",
                      "text": "Pick a game...",
                      "type": "select",
                      "options": [
                          {
                              "text": "Hearts",
                              "value": "hearts"
                          },
                          {
                              "text": "Global Thermonuclear War",
                              "value": "war"
                          }
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  }

    console.log('JSON.stringify(element): '+JSON.stringify(element));
    params = {
      icon_emoji: ':r2:',
      attachments: JSON.stringify(element)
    }
    bot.postMessage(channel, '', params).always(function (data) {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises from the lack of a text field in the parameters that is passed to `bot.PostMessage`. Your params should be

```
params = {
  icon_emoji: ':r2:',
  text: "Would you like to play a game?",
  response_type: "in_channel",
  attachments: element
}
```

and the element now should start from the actual attachment

```
const element = [
      {
          "text": "Choose a game to play",
          "fallback": "If you could read this message, you'd be choosing something fun to do right now.",
          "color": "#3AA3E3",
          "attachment_type": "default",
          "callback_id": "game_selection",
          "actions": [
              {
                  "name": "games_list",
                  "text": "Pick a game...",
                  "type": "select",
                  "options": [
                      {
                          "text": "Hearts",
                          "value": "hearts"
                      },
                      {
                          "text": "Global Thermonuclear War",
                          "value": "war"
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you.

The error disappear but when I run it on my Slack, it only prints the text "Would you like to play a game?" and does not show a dropdown menu - any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue and found the solution.
The problem is that if only `attachments` field is added into the payload, it will report `no_text` error. But if `text` field is added, slack message will only show the text content.

The solution:
When we want to display `attachments`, we need to add a basic `blocks` field instead of `text` field. Something like

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "bar"
            }
        }
    ],
    "attachments": [
        {
            "color": "#FF0000",
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "section",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "mrkdwn",
                        "text": "foo"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If putting the above payload into the [Slack build kit](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/), it will be a misleading. That's also why I stuck with the issue.

I would recommend to use [chat.postMessage test](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/test) to debug the payload. It will work like a charm.